# Wage difference in pay period for same weekly hours worked

Tags: united-states, employment, payroll-taxes

If I get paid biweekly, but missed a pay period, so get a check  for  four weeks instead, should not my net simply be double what I normally get for 2 weeks?  They increased my tax deductions, so that my pay is less than what it normally would be if I divide the 4 week check in half.  I worked the same number of hours every week.

Comment: Could someone explain what “missing a pay period” mean? Aren’t money sent via bank; how can someone “not” receive the money?

Comment: @Kyslik: In many companies timesheets have to go through an approval process such as being certified for accuracy by a supervisor.  If the person responsible for doing that gets sick, goes on vacation, or whatever, it's possible for the processing to spill into the next period.

Answer (score 18):

Your reasoning is sound, and you are correct. What most likely happened is that they withheld as if you earned all that within one pay period. That could be someone on the payroll end not doing the calculation correctly, or not knowing how to override the default pay-period calculation, or an inflexible payroll software that doesn't allow for exceptions like that.

Comment: Note though that whatever the reason was, it will be rectified for sure in your tax filing next year. Unless you don't want to wait for that, and start a discussion with Payroll.

Comment: I was told by a previous employer's accountant/payroll that companies are required to tax you at the rate as if that was your regular paycheck. It's one of the tools the IRS uses to help ensure people aren't avoiding taxes.

Comment: @ChrisG I believe they are required to tax you as if you'll earn the same amount all year, but I don't think that means they have to over-withholding on back-pay. Probably easier to mush it all into one pay period though.

Comment: The way withholding (usually) works in the UK is:  Month 1 - multiply pay by 12/1, calculate annual tax, divide by 12/1, withhold that much.   Month 2 - multiply total pay (from month 1 *and* month 2) by 12/2, calculate annual tax, divide by 12/2, subtract tax already withheld, withhold the result .... and so on.  Basically, at any point, they calculate how much you should pay in total, subtract what you've already paid, and withhold the difference.

Comment: @MartinBonner: in US the default is to extrapolate each pay period separately (except that non-regular pay such as bonuses, overtime, back pay etc _may_ be separated and withheld at a fixed, non-bracketed percentage), but if both employer and employee agree they _can_ use the method you describe; see ['cumulative wages' (method) in pub 15A](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p15a#en_US_2018_publink1000236700)

Comment: @HartCO: _if_ employer treats back pay as separately-paid supplemental wages (which is their option, not required) they must withhold income tax at flat-rate 22%, which probably for most middle-class workers is higher than their normal bracket-based withholding.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 In the UK the method you describe *can* be used (it's called "month1/week1" - because it treats all payments as if they were the first); however neither employer nor employee have any choice in the matter.  It is entirely determined by HMRC (equivalent of IRS).